# PDF doesn't open on Internet Browser

Tags: internet-explorer, pdf, browser

I have a PDF which doesn't open in a new window of my browser (Internet Explorer). If try to refresh the page with "F5", the PDF won't open either. But if I click on the link and press "Enter" the PDF opens.

What's the difference between "F5" and "Enter"?

Others browsers don't open it either; it's on a remote web server and the document is generated dynamically.

Comment: Is it on a remote web server or a local filing system? What's the URL of this document? Do other browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Safari etc) exhibit the same behaviours? Is it a static file or dynamically generated? etc.

Comment: The others browsers don't open too, it's on a remote web server and the document is generated dynamically.

Comment: OK. Is it dynamically generated by your code? What language? What headers are supplied when it is delivered (this would be the thing I'd most look into)? Can we see a snippet of the generation code?

Answer (score 0):

We would need more information.. but i guess "Enter" creates a submit while F5 just reloads the page.